# How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have been using [NewtonSoft JSON Convert](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library to parse and convert JSON string to C# objects. But now I have came across a really awkward JSON string and I am unable to convert it into C# object because I cant make a C# class out of this JSON string.

Here is the JSON string

```
{
"1": {
    "fajr": "04:15",
    "sunrise": "05:42",
    "zuhr": "12:30",
    "asr": "15:53",
    "maghrib": "19:18",
    "isha": "20:40"
},
"2": {
    "fajr": "04:15",
    "sunrise": "05:42",
    "zuhr": "12:30",
    "asr": "15:53",
    "maghrib": "19:18",
    "isha": "20:41"
 } 
}
```

The C# class required to parse this JSON string should be like this:

```
public class 1 {

    public string fajr { get; set; }
    public string sunrise { get; set; }
    public string zuhr { get; set; }
    public string asr { get; set; }
    public string maghrib { get; set; }
    public string isha { get; set; }
}

public class 2 {

    public string fajr { get; set; }
    public string sunrise { get; set; }
    public string zuhr { get; set; }
    public string asr { get; set; }
    public string maghrib { get; set; }
    public string isha { get; set; }
}
```

But it cant be a true C# class because we know that Class names cannot start with a number.

It will be really great if anyone can suggest how to parse such type of json string.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. from what I see, you have a list of items with the same structure. So your class should represent that structure, NOT the list, and you should parse your JSON to a .NET List, not to several classes.

Comment: As soon as it looks like key-value pairs, the answer below is spot on

Comment: @Bartdude list or NOT the list?

Comment: Yeah there is another class which has the two properties one for class 1 and other for class 2

Comment: L.B. here unders explained this much more clearly than me :-)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can deserialize to a dictionary.

```
public class Item
{
    public string fajr { get; set; }
    public string sunrise { get; set; }
    public string zuhr { get; set; }
    public string asr { get; set; }
    public string maghrib { get; set; }
    public string isha { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);
```

Comment: thanks a ton..worked like a charm......problem solved. but still i dont know how it worked. can you please explain how dictionary worked ?

Comment: @TaLhaKhan Because your json represents key-value pairs. "1" is the key, `{...}` is the value.

Answer (score 48):

While the dictionary is the best solution for the specific case you had, the question you asked could also be interpreted as:

> how do I deserialize objects with property names that cannot be used
>   in C#?

For example what if you had

```
{
    "0": "04:15",
    "zzz": "foo"
}
```

Solution: use annotations:

```
public class Item
{
   [JsonProperty("0")]
   public string AnyName { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("zzz")]
   public string AnotherName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Of course, if the number of *Keys* and their names are known beforehand. Not suitable for dynamically created objects like `userid : {name:aa,surname:bb}, anotheruserid:{}`

Comment: @I4V If they are dynamically created objects you probably couldn't use predefined classes anyway.

Comment: @R0MANARMY I didn't mean it . Keys can be dynamic, for example a guid or an id comming from db. But its value is a known type. `{{1232574:{name:john}, 755344674:{name:doe}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extensions:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, T> ToObject<T>(this string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, T>>(json);
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }
}
```