# JSON serialize with item name from JSON-data

Tags: c#, json, json.net, c#-8.0

I am using C# and Restclient.Net and Newtonsoft to parse json-data as C# classes.

I am stuck on how to handle this "simple" JSON-data like this:

```
{
  "deliveryAreas": [
    "Item1",
    "Item2",
    "Item3",
    "Item16"
  ],
  "multiAreaEntries": [
    {
      "entryPerArea": {
        "Item1": 230.99,
        "Item2": 230.99,
        "Item3": 230.99,
        "Item16": 230.99
      }
    },
    {
      "entryPerArea": {
        "Item1": 221.35,
        "Item2": 221.35,
        "Item3": 221.35,
        "Item16": 221.35
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the names given in the "deliveryAreas" are the entries that I am getting in the "entryPerArea".

Visual Studios "parse json as class" makes the class like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string[] deliveryAreas { get; set; }
    public Multiareaentry[] multiAreaEntries { get; set; }
}

public class Multiareaentry
{
    public Entryperarea entryPerArea { get; set; }
}

public class Entryperarea
{
    public float Item1 { get; set; }
    public float Item2 { get; set; }
    public float Item3 { get; set; }
    public float Item16 { get; set; }
}
```

This class works, if the items are called Item1,2,3,16 but it fails on others names or number of fields
How can I make this dynamic?

---

If you query the same API on other data you could get this reply

```
{
  "deliveryAreas": [
    "Person1",
    "Country10",
    "SomethingElse"
  ],
  "multiAreaEntries": [
    {
      "entryPerArea": {
        "Person1": 730.99,
        "Country10": 930.99,
        "SomethingElse": 130.99
      }
    },
    {
      "entryPerArea": {
        "Person1": 130.99,
        "Country10": 530.99,
        "SomethingElse": 1130.99
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Which would give the result in C# "Parse JSON as class" like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string[] deliveryAreas { get; set; }
    public Multiareaentry[] multiAreaEntries { get; set; }
}

public class Multiareaentry
{
    public Entryperarea entryPerArea { get; set; }
}

public class Entryperarea
{
    public float Person1 { get; set; }
    public float Country10 { get; set; }
    public float SomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

So fields stated in "deliveryAreas" are the names using in the "entryPerArea" and they are dynamic generated.

How can I handle this in C# / JSON in a neat way?

Comment: What are the possible names for `entryPerArea`? Currently your example only shows `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3` and `Item16`, but no other situations.

Comment: It can be anything.... All fields are stated in the "deliveryAreas" is the fields that exists on the "Entryperarea" field.
So if it changed to "person1", "country3" or whatever, the "Entryprarea" will change.

Comment: When you provide a sample JSON file with different key names in the `entryPerArea` field for multiple `multiAreaEntries` entries, what class does Visual Studio generate then?

Comment: Declare `entryPerArea` as a `public Dictionary<string, double> entryPerArea { get; set; } = new();`.  [Deserializing JSON with unknown object names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38688570/3744182) is another duplicate.

Comment: That was great help @dbc and Progman, that fixed my queries! Thank you for the guide in the right way. Could not find this in search