# C# Deserialize Root JSON Unknown Keys

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a JSON like this and have to deserialize it:

```
{
  "0": {
    "foo_id":"xyz",
    "bar_id":"abc",
    "book": {
      "0": {
        "title":"hello",
        "author":"person_x"
      },
      "1": {
        "title":"hi",
        "author":"person_y"
      }
  },
  "1": {
    "foo_id":"xyz",
    "bar_id":"abc",
    "book": {
      "0": {
        "title":"hello",
        "author":"person_a"
      },
      "1": {
        "title":"bye",
        "author":"person_b"
      }
  },
  "random":"string",
  "other":"thing"
}
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901076/deserializing-json-when-key-values-are-unknown) question, except the answer given doesn't work, because I don't have the luxury of creating a class like this

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Object> Objects {get; set;}
}
```

If I do than the Objects field is null after deserialization.

Both the root object and book object are dynamic.

Any other approaches would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the JSON you have does *not* contains a `RootObject` that **holds** a dictionary, you can deserialize straight into a `Dictionary` like so:

**Class:**

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("foo_id")]
    public string FooId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bar_id")]
    public string BarId { get; set; }
}
```

**Deserialize:**

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

---

## Update:

Since you have changed the original JSON in your question, the second given JSON can be deserialized as so:

**Class:**

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> Items { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("random")]
    public string Random { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("other")]
    public string Other { get; set; }
}
```

**Deserialize:**

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: I still have a RootObject class, which is the one I would like to deserialize, because it has some other data I need. Thanks

Comment: @querty123 it's important to know the whole structure of the complete JSON response in order to deserialize