# JSON Deserialize to list C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

My JSON has this information:

```json
[
 {
  "era_1":{"technology_cost":"10000"},
  "era_2":{"technology_cost":"15000"},
  "era_3":{"technology_cost":"20000"},
  "era_4":{"technology_cost":"25000"},
  "era_5":{"technology_cost":"30000"}
 }
]
```

I want to do:

```
EraData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClassEra>>(JSON);
```

Being ClassEra

```
public class ClassEra
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string technology_cost { get; set; }
}
```

And obviously it doesn't work.

I don't understand the type of data that is coming out of the deserializer.

By the way I'm using Newtonsoft.

Comment: You need to account for the `"era_X"` names.  I reckon those are runtime-only names so use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, ClassEra>>>(JSON);`.  See as shown in [Deserializing JSON when key values are unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24901245/3744182).

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you are declaring your class wrongly. The JSON is a list of 1 object which then has multiple objects.

Comment: @dbc i dont know the number of era_x that are coming so what sould i do?

Comment: @Filipe - I told you.  Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, ClassEra>>>(JSON)`.  The `era_X` names will be deserialized as the dictionary keys, the `{"technology_cost":"XX"}` objects as the dictionary values.  Also you can remove `name` from `ClassEra`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
EraData  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, ClassEra>>>(JSON);
```

And class will be

```
    public class ClassEra
    {
        public string technology_cost { get; set; }
    }
```

Fetching details

I prefer to use dictionary because time complexity of fetching value is O(1) by key like `dic[key]`

```
//By this :- get complete dictionary
var dic = EraData[0]; //and iterate by foreach loop 
 
//by this you can get all technology cost:- 
var technology_cost = EraData.SelectMany(x => x.Values);
```

Screenshots

`Dictionary`
[image]

`Technology Cost`
[image]

Comment: How do i get the value of the class in the dictionary?

Comment: By this :- get complete dictionary var dic = EraData[0]; and iterate by foreach loop

Comment: by this you can get all technology cost:-  var technology_cost = EraData.SelectMany(x => x.Values);

Answer (score 1):

The json format is not what you are trying to capture as class object. Your targeted json should be :

```
[{"name":"era_1","technology_cost":"10000"},
{"name":"era_2","technology_cost":"15000"},
{"name":"era_3","technology_cost":"20000"},
{"name":"era_4","technology_cost":"25000"},
{"name":"era_5","technology_cost":"30000"}]
```

Comment: That is just how the data comes, cant do anything

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on what @Pradeep wrote, if you want to know the era name you could select it like this

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, ClassEra>>>(json);

var eras = dict.SelectMany(x => x.Keys.Select(k => new ClassEra()
{
    Name = k,
    TechnologyCost = x[k].TechnologyCost
}));

public class ClassEra
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("technology_cost")] public string TechnologyCost { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was tryind to what dbc and Pradeep said but couldnt get the "technology_cost" out. Is it because the _ is not supported?

Comment: It's supported, it's just the structure was not the same as in your class. In C# the convention is to name things in `PascalCase` and not `snake_case`, that's why I changed it, but it still works with both.