# JSON.Net - cannot deserialize the current json object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'system.collections.generic.list`1

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a JSON like

```
{
  "40": {
    "name": "Team A vs Team B",
    "value": {
      "home": 1,
      "away": 0
    }
  },
  "45": {
    "name": "Team A vs Team C",
    "value": {
      "home": 2,
      "away": 0
    }
  },
  "50": {
    "name": "Team A vs Team D",
    "value": {
      "home": 0,
      "away": 2
    }
  }
}
```

So it's kind of list of matches. And I have the class to deserialize it into:

```
public class Match
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public Value Values { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "home")]
    public int Home { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "away")]
    public int Away { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to deserialize json like this:

```
var mList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Match>>(jsonstr);
```

But i am getting exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ClassNameHere]' because
>   the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

If i change the code like:

```
var mList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstr);
```

Then it serializes but not as a list, as a object. How can I fix this?

Comment: Put a [] (bracket) from start and end of your jsonstr

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536533/how-can-i-parse-a-json-string-that-would-cause-illegal-c-sharp-identifiers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, you should ask Deserializer for **`IDictionary<string, Match>`**

```
var mList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, Match>>(jsonstr);
```

And the first element would have key **"40"** and the value will be the `Match` instance

Other words this part:

```
"40": {
    "name": "Team A vs Team B",
    "value": {
      "home": 1,
      "away": 0
    }
```

will result in KeyValuePair:

```
key - "40"
value - Match { Name = "Team",  ... }
```

Comment: You are not suppose to change the document, but use the programming code to manage the document.

Comment: @SterlingDiaz not sure what do you mean? I followed the JSON structure to show how to represent it in C#... so, I am really not sure what is your point here

Answer (score 4):

```
"50": {
         "name": "Team A vs Team D",
         "value": {
                    "home": 0,
                    "away": 2
                  }
      }
```

The desirializer works correctly. In this json code `value` is an object. 
Try with this:

```
"50": {
         "name": "Team A vs Team D",
         "value": [{
                     "home": 0,
                     "away": 2
                  }]
      }
```

In this json code `value` is declared as an array of objects. Notice the `[` and `]`