# How to return as objects from firebase using firesharp

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fire-sharp

[image: Firebase database]

For this i want to get all the vehicles as a list of vehicle objects

```
FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("Vehicles/");
List<Data> vehicles = response.ResultAs<List<Data>>().ToList();
```

this gives a JSON serialization exception.
The data class is as follows:

```
internal class Data
{
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string vehicleNo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645952/json-net-cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-namevalue-in)

```
var mList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, Match>>(jsonstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

So we create a dictionary, its basically a Map of Id of the object to the object itself for every entry in the snapshot. We are using a deserializer from the Newton package.

```
Dictionary<string, Data> = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(response.Body.ToString()) ?? new();
```