# Serialize to JSON with parenthesis in property name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using paypal api to do some payment stuff.

If I look at [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) some field are in the form `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT`. That's fine for me because I has a request class like this:

```
public class SetExpressCheckoutRequest 
{
     public string PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT { get; set; }
}
```

That works. Now I need to use the [PAY operation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) which has fields like

```
receiverList.receiver(0).email
```

Since parenthesis are not allowed in c# property names, how am I supposed to write a corresponding property on my request class. I would prefer not to use `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Can I configure JSON.net to handle an alternative like convert `_` to `(`   ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536533/how-can-i-parse-a-json-string-that-would-cause-illegal-c-sharp-identifiers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize JSON property names with the `JsonProperty` attribute:

```
public class Request
{
    [JsonProperty("receiverList.receiver(0).email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: D'OH. I've used this before. My brain must have not woke up yet, thanks