# how to convert json response to c# dictionary?

Tags: json2csharp

I have the following json response and I want to convert it into C# model.
I am facing the issue that it has key value as integer and when I'm converting it into C# through converter it is making as many classes as these values. how to convert it as dictionary while deserialization.

```
"data": {
    "564448665437833501": {
        "city_name": "Mount Cook",
        "country_name": "New Zealand",
        "country_code": "NZ"
    },
    "5862745215379501543": {
        "city_name": "Coolangatta",
        "country_name": "Australia",
        "country_code": "AU"
    },
}
```

Comment: Any body please help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536533/how-can-i-parse-a-json-string-that-would-cause-illegal-c-sharp-identifiers)