# C# Get JSON value

Tags: c#, json, parsing, steam

I'm trying to parse some JSON, but I'm running into a problem. I'm trying to get the name of the item.
JSON: http://steamcommunity.com/id/xejuicy/inventory/json/730/2/

Code I tried:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string theItems = wc.DownloadString(string.Format("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{0}/inventory/json/730/2/", steamUser.SteamID.ConvertToUInt64()));
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(theItems);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", dynObj.rgDescriptions,dynObj);
foreach (var name in dynObj)
{
    foreach (var subname in name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", subname.name);
    }
}
```

If you are familiar with CS:GO, i want to get all CS:GO items from steam (even crates), everything from that game I have in inventory and get its name.

Error: JValue doesn't contain definition for name.
Where it occurs: second foreach (Console.WriteLine("{0}", subname.name);)

It's not duplicate because i successfully deserialized JSON and can take value but CAN'T get subvalue... Question already answered though.

Comment: Need to add a bunch more info. Like, what is the error? When doesit occur?

Comment: That first `Console.WriteLine` call has only one parameter in the format string, but gets 2 parameters...

Comment: That's not the problem tho. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(theItems);
foreach (var desc in dynObj.rgDescriptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", desc.Name, desc.Value.name);
}
```

Comment: Problem is, that i don't know the .Value, look on JSON... It's numbers of item... like "527635071_0"

Comment: @XeJuicY Just try it..It works.....

Comment: Oh my, you are my savior @Eser