# Deserialize json to anonymous C# object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I need to deserialize custom JSON to anonymous C# object.

My sample JSON (can be any, even with nested properties as objects):

```
var json = "{ 'Surname': 'Wick'}";
```

And I want to be deserialized as:

```
var jsonResult = new { Surname = "Wick" };
```

But I end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32187603/6400526) for Newtonsoft Json

Comment: The generic type you pass should be `dynamic` and not `object`

Comment: @GiladGreen If use *dynamic* it ends up the same like I use *object*

Comment: test the two but do `jsonResult.Surname` in the watch

Comment: @GiladGreen http://imgur.com/a/Bjxqu

Comment: I know :) that is why access the property `jsonResult.Surname` - with the object you'll get an exception, with dynamic you'll get the value. In both cases you get a dynamic object but in the `object` case it is cased to object... Also you can have a look under the `Dynamic View` line:)

Comment: @GiladGreen *Json.Decode* gives better result, why JsonCoverter can't do the same?

Comment: then use `Json.Decode`... different frameworks, each with its own implementation

Comment: @GiladGreen Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You are welcome :) hope it helped

Comment: In Json.Net, use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeAnonymousType__1.htm) and give it an example of the anonymous type you want to deserialize into.