# C# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject populating list with null

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a class called `LatLong` which stores two `strings`, a `latitude` and `longitude`. I have another class called `LatLongs` which is a list of type `LatLong`

```
public class LatLongs
{
    public List<LatLong> latlongs { get; set; }
    public string location_name { get; set; }
}

public class LatLong
{
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I have another class called `Locations` which holds a `JSON` string called `geofence_coordinates`

The JSON string has two fields, `latitude` and `longitude` and is used to store these values on an SQL server. The JSON strings look like this:

```
[  
   {  
      " latitude ":"-34.95771393255739",
      " longitude ":"138.46961975097656"
   },
   {  
      " latitude ":"-34.9520861634788",
      " longitude ":"138.57330322265625"
   },
   {  
      " latitude ":"-35.00947127349485",
      " longitude ":"138.50017547607422"
   },
   {  
      " latitude ":"-35.00806525651258",
      " longitude ":"138.57467651367188"
   }
]
```

Below is where my code is not working properly. I have a list of type `Locations` called `coords`. I create a `List<LatLongs>` which I intend to populate with my JSON coordinates, but at the moment the JSON is not working properly and it is being fed `null`

```
List<Locations> coords = await locationTable.Where(u => u.fk_company_id == viewModel.UserData.fk_company_id).ToListAsync();
List<LatLongs> latLongs = coords.Select(c => new LatLongs
  {
      latlongs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LatLong>>(c.geofence_coordinates)
  }).ToList();
```

Am I used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` wrong?

Comment: Do those JSON property names really have blank spaces at the beginning and end?  E.g. `" latitude "` starts and ends with a space.

Comment: Is that the complete json? where is the wrapping object presented in it?

Comment: @dbc is JSON space sensitive?

Comment: @GiladGreen sorry I don't understand the question, I'm new to JSON

Comment: What is the exact content of `c.geofence_coordinates` when you debug it?

Comment: I'm an idiot, the reason is because there are spaces in the JSON where there shouldn't be. Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: @Barney Chambers, if you cant remove spaces your can add spaces to json convert public class LatLong
    {
        [JsonProperty(" latitude ")]
        public string latitude { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(" longitude ")]
        public string longitude { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON property names includes spaces at the beginning and end:

```
" latitude ":"-35.00947127349485"  
 ^        ^  
 |        |
 here and here
```

Json.NET will not automatically bind JSON properties with spaces in their names to c# properties by trimming the spaces.  And since c# identifiers cannot include space characters, you need to chose one of the possibilities from [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536533/how-can-i-parse-a-json-string-that-would-cause-illegal-c-sharp-identifiers), for instance by marking your properties with a [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute:

```
public class LatLong
{
    [JsonProperty(" latitude ")]
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(" longitude ")]
    public string longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UerJ32).