# Need help to deserialize JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json, string, serialization

I have a JSON string as below.

```
{"checkbox-1026":"eba8786c-f31d-4c5a-92ce-2d8ffd7c1066","checkbox-1027":"1b529116-1c58-4ac5-ad9d-04bd0d296335"}
```

I need to get values `"eba8786c-f31d-4c5a-92ce-2d8ffd7c1066"` and `"1b529116-1c58-4ac5-ad9d-04bd0d296335"`.

Can anyone help me to get the values?

Comment: [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) should be your solution.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: there are plenty of examples at [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Will the json string always have the same keys?

Comment: use JSON.NET and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>

Comment: I have tried the above possible solutions but not working. It is not static, it is just example data which I get from CheckBoxGroup checked values in controller in ext.net mvc. It is not exactly in json format. So please check the data and help me for possible solution. Thank you.

Comment: See [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24536533/10263)

Answer (score 1):

Try with Newtonsoft.JSON. Sample below shows how to get those values

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(j1);
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
}
```

Here is working demo link https://dotnetfiddle.net/MGkRIA

Comment: Can you please check my key value pairs? In order to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject, you need to have same values in key string. But in my case the key string values are also different.