# Problems Deserializing Json attributes preceeded by '#' using Newtonsoft-C#-.Net

Tags: c#, json

I am successfully deserializing Json files using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() but I am having troubles with a fairly large json file with many structures.  The problems is in the Stats subclasses which all have a category and abbreviation that are preceeded with @ and a text attribute preceeded by a #.  The values are all comming out null.

Here is the class structure

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SalaryCapData.ConsumeJson.Models.Daily
{

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Dailyplayerstats dailyplayerstats { get; set; }
        }

        public class Dailyplayerstats
        {
            public string lastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
            public Playerstatsentry[] playerstatsentry { get; set; }
        }

        public class Playerstatsentry
        {
            public Player player { get; set; }
            public Team team { get; set; }
            public Stats stats { get; set; }
        }

        public class Player
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string JerseyNumber { get; set; }
            public string Position { get; set; }
        }

        public class Team
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
        }

        public class Stats
        {
            public Atbats AtBats { get; set; }
            public Runs Runs { get; set; }
            public Hits Hits { get; set; }
            public Secondbasehits SecondBaseHits { get; set; }
            public Thirdbasehits ThirdBaseHits { get; set; }
            public Homeruns Homeruns { get; set; }
            public Earnedruns EarnedRuns { get; set; }
            public Unearnedruns UnearnedRuns { get; set; }
  .....
        public class Atbats
        {
            public string category { get; set; }
            public string abbreviation { get; set; }
            public string #text { get; set; }
        }

        public class Runs
        {
            public string category { get; set; }
            public string abbreviation { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
        }

        public class Hits
        {
            public string category { get; set; }
            public string abbreviation { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
        }

        public class Secondbasehits
        {
            public string category { get; set; }
            public string abbreviation { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
        }


}
```

Here is a sample of the json 
    {

```
"dailyplayerstats": {
    "lastUpdatedOn": "2018-02-22 8:10:18 AM",
    "playerstatsentry": [
      {
        "player": {
          "ID": "10437",
          "LastName": "Abreu",
          "FirstName": "Jose",
          "JerseyNumber": "79",
          "Position": "1B"
        },
        "team": {
          "ID": "119",
          "City": "Chicago",
          "Name": "White Sox",
          "Abbreviation": "CWS"
        },
        "stats": {
          "AtBats": {
            "@category": "Batting",
            "@abbreviation": "AB",
            "#text": "5"
          },
          "Runs": {
            "@category": "Batting",
            "@abbreviation": "R",
            "#text": "1"
          },
          "Hits": {
            "@category": "Batting",
            "@abbreviation": "H",
            "#text": "2"
          },
```

yadda, yadda, yadda.

Not sure if it the reason why the 'text' attribute is coimming back null but notice the '#'?  Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't seen a JSON file like this before. This almost looks like a weird XML to JSON thing with `@` denoting the attributes and `#text` being the inner text.

Comment: Disregard the '#text' in the sample code I posted.  I was just screwing around - I tried everything else..

Comment: You can try tagging the properties with the JSON names. `[JsonProperty("#text")]` https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify.  The #text in the class definitions was something I was trying and forgot to remove before posting.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Your question specifically asks about the preceeding `#`. The whole point of that attribute is for you to put the name of the property from the JSON file. Whatever it is, fill it in and try  ;)

Comment: Thank you TyCobb.  I will try that.  Would Notepad++ be a good editor for that?  Actually, I guess I need to write a program to do that.  I will be getting these files daily.  I will try it.

Comment: Now that I think of it, there must be a property in the Convert method that can ignore certain characters?

Comment: That attribute goes onto your C# class property.

Comment: That JSON was clearly converted from XML using Json.NET's [Converting between JSON and XML](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm) functionality.  Why not deserialize the XML directly?  But if you don't want to do that, see [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536739/3744182).  You'll need `[JsonProperty("#text")]`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the support.  I don't anything about an XML conversion.  The sample that I posted here came directly from the feed.  I certainly did not do any conversion.  I will look at  "How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers".

Comment: Yippeeee!! Success!!  :)  Thank you everyone...