# Deserializing flat json c#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to grab all elements from flat json. I am able to see the count of the multiple items but I am unable to see the values for each list property.

The JSON:

```
    {  
   "Key":"C23432151461561",
   "OrderId": 129012092109,
   "SteamId":12341234321,
   "AppId":1234132,
   "ItemCount":2,
   "Language":"en",
   "Currency":"CAD",
   "itemid[0]":1,
   "qty[0]":2,
   "amount[0]":12,
   "description[0]":"majora's mask",
   "itemid[1]":1,
   "qty[1]":2,
   "amount[1]":12,
   "description[1]":"mario's hat",
    }
```

[image]

Models

```
class Descriptions
{
    public string descriptions { get; set; }
}

public class Amounts
{
    public int amounts { get; set; }
}

public class Qtys
{
    public int qtys { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public int itemids { get; set; }
}
public class InitTxn
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public int orderid { get; set; }
    public long steamid { get; set; }
    public int appid { get; set; }
    public int itemcount { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public List<Items> itemid { get; set; }
    public List<Qtys> qty { get; set; }
    public List<Amounts> amount { get; set; }
    public List<Descriptions> description { get; set; }
}
```

Post Method

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public string InitRequest([FromBody] InitTxn initTxn)
    {}
```

I need to be able to see the values for the List properties. Thanks

Comment: Replace `public List<Items> itemid { get; set; }` by `public List<int> itemid { get; set; }` Should be same for other list properties

Comment: That is a very weird way to do JSON. Why is `"itemid[0]":1,` used, rather than have `itemid` pointing to an array?

Comment: The names like `"description[0]"` are somewhat unusual... You probably looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536533/how-can-i-parse-a-json-string-that-would-cause-illegal-c-sharp-identifiers (unless you trying to represent arrays that look very different in JSON)

Comment: @mjwills I am using steam api, and this is how they handle json unfortunately

Comment: It's the first time I see this format. But your screenshot is a proof that should work. Do you have links about this json format and/or api that use it?

Comment: @Kalten yea, steammicrotxn api https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamMicroTxn#InitTxn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is ok with your sample except your data model classes. You use intermediate classes (like `Qtys` or `Items`) but the json only expose array of primitive type. And not an array of object with a property XXX.

To summarize, your model only need to look like the following class :

```
public class InitTxn
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public int orderid { get; set; }
    public long steamid { get; set; }
    public int appid { get; set; }
    public int itemcount { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public List<int> itemid { get; set; }
    public List<int> qty { get; set; }
    public List<int> amount { get; set; }
    public List<string> description { get; set; }
}
```